# installApolloCodegen is failing

Tags: android, apollo

I am getting error when trying to build the project. It fails at `installAppolloCodegen` with the following trace. I am using Node `v16.17.0` , npm `8.5.0`, using windows 10 and Android stuido is chipmunk.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! argv "D:\\AndroidStudioWorkspace\\wowe-android-app\\app\\.gradle\\nodejs\\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\\node.exe" "D:\\AndroidStudioWorkspace\\wowe-android-app\\app\\.gradle\\nodejs\\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "apollo-codegen@0.17.0-alpha.13" "--save" "--save-exact"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPROTO 101057795:error:1408D07B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_key_exchange:bad signature:openssl\ssl\s3_clnt.c:2010:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\AndroidStudioWorkspace\wowe-android-app\app\build\apollo-codegen\npm-debug.log
```